# Pasar de un sistema de ecuaciones a la notación matricial con NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, matrices

¿Cómo puedo pasar de un sistema de ecuaciones a la notación matricial como se ve más abajo ocupando los arrays o  matrices de numpy en python 2.7?  el siguiente sistema viene en formato de string

```
22X1+1X2+1X3+2X4=24
2X1+2X2-1X3=20
2X3-2X4=20
4X4=16
```

esto necesito, como se ve cada columna corresponde a una variable del sistema de ecuaciones.

```
([22,1,1,2,24],
[2,2,-1,0,20],
[0,0,2,-2,20],
[0,0,0,4,15])
```

o algo parecido.

Comment: Hola @Joaquin Tapia Jorquera. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías comentar qué intentaste hasta ahora? -No importa si no está funcionando, es mucho más sencillo contestar a partir de donde llegaste. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Encontrarás el enlace a **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido Joaquin. Si tienes algo hecho deberías poner el código y mirarte el tipo de preguntas que son aceptadas en este sitio como te ha recomendado @Mariano. Tu pregunta tal y como está puede terminar siendo cerrada, más aún cuando parece ser una tarea. ¿Las ecuaciones como las recibe tu programa, como cadenas de texto?. Si es así, una posible solución sería usar el módulo [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) y mediante [expresiones regulares](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) separar variables y coeficientes. Una vez hecho esto construir la matriz con `numpy` es trivial.

Comment: Adicionalmente a lo que te mencionan, puedes ir revisando la documentación de NumPy, podrías comenzar por [aquí](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html). Además si lo que quieres es resolver el sistema deberías revisar la documentación de la función [`solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html), misma que trae un ejemplo mínimo pero bastante ilustrativo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es un mero parseo de strings. Su tienes `"22X1+1X2+1X3+2X4=24"`Puedes usar la función `string.split('+')` para separar los términos en una lista y obtienes `["22X1", "1X2", "1X3", "2X4=24"]`. Luego lo que haces es aislar el numero de antes de la x. Para ello puedes hacer un `string.split('X')` `["22", "1"],...`y en el primer elemento de la lista que retorne estará el coeficiente que debes rescatar.
Al hacer ésto sobre una ecuación tienes una lista de coeficientes para la lista, recuerda usar la función `int("22")# = 22` para convertir el string "22" al numero 22.
Sólo debes continuar haciéndolo para todas las ecuaciones con algunos ciclos for, luego haces una lista de listas (Correspondiente a cada fila de la matriz) y se la pasas al método `array = np.array(ListaDeListas)`, donde la lista de listas es algo asi: `[[22,1,1,2,24],[2,2,-1,0,20],...)`. Este método te creará una matriz de numpy como deseas.

Espero que te haya ayudado. Creo que las instrucciones son bastante claras pero de todas maneras puedes preguntarme aquí abajo. No pretendo programar el parseo de esas ecuaciones pero se ve un problema simple de resolver.

Comment: Y con los signos menos  "-", se haria lo mismo?  Porque no se puede hacer un doble split al mismo tiempo u.u

Comment: @JoaquinTapiaJorquera Porque necesitas hacer split al mismo tiempo? Puedes hacerlo de manera secuecial y obtendrás el mismo resultado.

Comment: @JoaquinTapiaJorquera la forma que propone Vicente es totalmente plausible si tus variables son siempre de la forma `x_`. Las claves te las a dado, solo te queda pensar un poquito como implementarlo. Aplicas `split()` con el `=`, luego con el `+`, luego sobre el `-`, luego sobre las `x` y por último usas el nombre de la variable para colocar su constante en el lugar apropiado de la matriz.